# WSL version difference on windows 11

Tags: version, windows-subsystem-for-linux

After installing WSL as per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install) guide, I am seeing a difference in WSL when running the following commands:

```
wsl -v
```

and

```
wsl -l -v
```

The first command returns:

```
WSL version: 1.2.5.0
```

second command returns:

```
 NAME            STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu          Running         2
```

Why are both not returning version 2?

Answer (score 0):

The following command returns the installed version of WSL 1:

> wsl -v

When the following command returns the list of the installed Linux distributions and WSL version they are currently on:

> wsl -l -v

To make an installed distro "Ubuntu"(in your example) match WSL version 1 you need to run the following command:

> wsl --set-version Ubuntu 1

To see your selected default distribution and WSL version run the following command:

> wsl --status

**The wsl.exe is technically a WSL(Windows Subsystem for Linux) 1 version app that can be used to covert individual Linux distributions to WSL 1 or WSL 2. In your case "Ubuntu" distro installed on your system was converted to WSL 2.**

Changing the WSL version to 1 can be beneficial if you plan to edit files inside distribution with any Windows applications. And if you only access files from within distribution then go with WSL version 2. The performance difference is significant which is why switching between versions is still practical. Further, read on the comparison between WSL 1 and WSL 2 - [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions#whats-new-in-wsl-2)